# Which file format support for installing RHEL 8 for /boot/efi while / in LVM?

Tags: rhel, boot, uefi

RHEL 8 supports UEFI in Secure Boot enabled as well as with Disabled mode. That is a very good change, as Most of the new machines only support UEFI mode.

But while installing RHEL 8 with UEFI mode, why in custom partition; I had to choose both

- `/boot`  in standard partition
- `/boot/efi`

The Custom partition wold looks like this

```
/                LVM 
/boot            Standard
/boot/efi        
/swap            LVM
```

Why not only `/boot/efi` works ?

I tried going with `/boot/efi` in different file formats, removing `/boot`. But every time it says format not supported.

Now I am stuck with this question help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

`/boot/efi` must be a standard partition formatted to *EFI System Partition* (just an alias to *FAT* used in the installer).

`/boot` must also be on a separate standard partition (or MD array with metadata version 0.90). This is a limitation enforced by the installer, strictly speaking separate `/boot` is not needed with LVM, but Anaconda doesn't allow it.
Some more information about why `/boot` is not supported on LVM can be found [in RHEL bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998710) and [in the customer portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39416) (requires subscription/RH account).